# restore suse grub

Tags: ubuntu, grub, opensuse, dual-boot

I upgraded my ubuntu and that resulted in its grub loader being used. I have a triboot of windows, ubuntu and suse. I prefer the suse bootloader which I was using before the ubuntu updates. I would like to restore the suse boot loader from yast. How do i do it?

Answer (score 3):

The generic procedure to restore Grub is

1. Boot into something Linux (either live CD or on disk, but must have Grub commands available) -- I don't know about other *nix
2. Mount the partition that holds the OS with Grub to be fixed, be sure to mount the separated boot partition if you have it
3. Issue the following command, remember to replace `/mnt/suse` and `/dev/sda` with your mount point and device
   `grub-setup -d /mnt/suse /dev/sda`

Alternatively, after step 2, you can `chroot` to `/mnt/suse` and from there execute

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

I find the [Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20GRUB%202) very informative at this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to boot into SuSE, and run (as root) `grub-install /dev/sda` (replace /dev/sda with the boot device on your computer.  You'll want to update your /boot/grub/menu.lst in SuSE to include an entry for Ubuntu.

Comment: that command fails.

Comment: How does it fail?  Are you running `/usr/sbin/grub-install`?  Are you installing it to the right drive?