# What preparations should I make before reinstalling windows?

Tags: windows, grub2, reinstall

Since Windows still does not offer means to skip rewriting the MBR, what can I do *before* reinstalling Windows to get Grub2 back into the MBR as easy as possible? (I'll also appreciate it if the answer then describes *how* to restore Grub)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people have been able to get NTLDR to chain to grub:
http://stringofthoughts.wordpress.com/2009/04/27/booting-linux-from-ntloader-windows-bootloader/

Although in practice it's easier to use a live CD. I usually do something like:

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/somewhere # mount the linux partition
chroot /mnt/somewhere bash
mount /proc
grub-install /dev/sda2
```

Comment: +1, I took the liberty to quote your answer to my similar question [at SU](http://superuser.com/questions/257049/what-to-consider-when-evaluating-windows-multipoint-server-2011/259118#259118), but if you repost it there yourself I'll accept your post and delete my quote

Answer (score 3):

Nothing. Just make sure that you have a live CD around. After you install Windows and by the way let it overwrite the MBR, just boot into the live CD and restore Grub.

Regarding restoring Grub, it has been [asked before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=restore+grub).

Comment: +1 and thanks (I accept pjc50's answer though for the link and the minimal code) **edit** though [your answer here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/restore-suse-grub/6838#6838) also helps